# The `gesture detector` does not work, and it does not produce any error

Tags: flutter

The `gesture detector` does not work, and it does not produce any error, it just does nothing when I  click the widget `ToolSetRight`, I'm `passing data` to the `ToolSetRight` widget, can that be a reason that it doesn't work?

```
children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('button');
                
              },
              child: ToolSetRight(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                 
              ),
            ),
```

**EDIT:** the `ToolSetRight` as follows

```
 Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
          child: Container(
            child: Material(
              color: Color(0xff0D8EEB),  
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.white,
                onTap: () {
                   
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: widget.width,
                    height: widget.height,
                    child:
                        FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: widget.icon)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Can you show your ```ToolSetRight()``` Widget code?

Comment: Is it wraped in a `Stack`?

Comment: @RaineDaleHolgado added code above

Comment: @quoci yes, it is. Added code above

Comment: InkWell got `onTap` too. Check if it `ate` the gesture.

Comment: @iwpz yes you're right, once it got deleted the `gesture works`, but now `inkwell` does not work, it seems like inkwell needs the `on tap` there to work.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl I guess you want to make a button. `GestureDetector` with child can be a button, `InkWell ` can be a button, you can replace your `GestureDetector` with `InkWell `, and remove your `InkWell `. What I mean is, you only need `one` `onTap`.

Comment: no, I need this to be a rounded rectangle which contains an icon in the middle and it should ripple and do a click event, when clicked. Don't know why a simple setup like this is so complex in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `GestureDetector` didnt work is because it doesnt know where it got pressed on Inkwell or GestureDetector widget. Removed the parent GestureDetector Widget and call the onTap in the ToolSetRight.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ButtonT(
          onTap: () {
            print("Pressed");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonT extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const ButtonT({Key key,required this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonTState createState() => _ButtonTState();
}

class _ButtonTState extends State<ButtonT> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      child: Container(
        child: Text("pResss"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
  ToolSetRight(
    ontap: (){
      print("On pressed");
    }
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.home,
    ),
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
  ),
```

Comment: Produces `error`: `The getter 'onTap' isn't defined for the type 'ToolSetRight'`  it highlights the `widget.onTap` that you newly added above.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl , I tested it and it works fine.. I will changed the example given

Comment: @Pretty_Girl, have you added it on the Contructor? ```final VoidCallback onTap;``?

Comment: Adding it gives another error: `The parameter 'onTap' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.`

Comment: I managed to remove the errors by placing "?" inbetween your `final VoidCallback onTap;` as `final VoidCallback? onTap;` but now the `inkwell` is gone, it no longer functions